# How do you use Rope Darts on PC?

Tags: assassins-creed-3, assassins-creed-4-black-flag, assassins-creed-rogue

I just got curious on what the Rope Darts are (in Assassin's Creed 3, Assassin's Creed 4: Black Flag, and in Assassin's Creed: Rogue). I don't know how to use them though. I want to know how to I can use them in all ways, like pulling enemies closer to you and hanging them from trees. I could not find the PC key binds for them. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has been quite a while since I played AC:3 and 4, so I can't tell you which buttons to press however, I can tell you what to do.

Aim at someone passing by, the closer to being below you , the better, once they're highlighted you're able to use the action button (I think it's E, however like I said, not 100% sure) and you'll use the rope dart, hitting them and hanging them on the branch where you were.

Edit:
When the throw dart icon comes up at the top, press that button and hold S.

Comment: ty @mugen2099 for the right button =)